# Jquery easing plugin browser compatibility?

Tags: jquery

What is JQuery Easing Plugin 's browser compatibility? Is there any easing plugin with a wide range of browser compatibility?

I am thinking on this because I am looking for a CSS3 animate and transform accurate polyfill, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easing plugin is just a set of mathematical functions.

[View source](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js).

It is supported by any browser that runs JavaScript.

---

Any browser supported by jQuery will run those easing functions:

- `1.x` branch: IE6+
- `2.x` branch: IE9+

Comment: Thanks, your right, I got a little confused by another plugin that relied on CSS to execute it's animations. Thanks ;)